# How to fetch contacts and print them using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I would like to fetch contacts and populate them in a listview, I read the flutter documentation:

```
// Get all contacts on device
Iterable<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
```

How can I access the contact name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Contact** is a class, and its fields are the following :

```
String displayName, givenName, middleName, prefix, suffix, familyName;

// Company
String company, jobTitle;

// Email addresses
Iterable<Item> emails = [];

// Phone numbers
Iterable<Item> phones = [];

// Post addresses
Iterable<PostalAddress> postalAddresses = [];

// Contact avatar/thumbnail
Uint8List avatar;
```

you can access the contact name by iterating throw the array contacts , and access each fields , as the following :

```
contacts.forEach((contact){
      print(contact.displayName);
});
```

Comment: how can i get phonenumber?? @Yousuf AL-Mawali

Comment: @urvashi did you get a solution to your comment

Comment: If you can find the solution you implemented just post it here and say it is a modification of the original question's answer

Comment: you can use this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contacts package

Answer (score 2):

To get phone number ...this is my code:

```dart
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void printContactsNumber() {
    Iterable<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false);
    List<Contact> contactsList = contacts.toList();

    // now print first 50 number's contancts
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        contactsList[0].phones.first.value.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [flutter_contacts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contacts) package
In example, you'll find your solution with ease.